# HDRP support for Android, Unity?

Tags: android, oculusquest

I am building a VR android application for Oculus Quest 2 using HDRP. I am aware that on the Unity site it says that the HDRP support for Android is not there yet. But I wanted to confirm if there were any updates and/or the article on Unity is old [Oculus Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wUAx.png). Since I am getting an error of "The platform Android with the graphic API Direct3D11 is not supported with High Definition Render Pipeline".

FYI I am using the Vulkan Graphics API.

Comment: Did you find anything out? I'm curious about the same.

Answer (score 0):

The reported API is the one selected as Windows API (which is a bug).
Android will simply (and sadly) not build if you use HDRP, even though Vulkan does support compute shaders